# Powerline fonts displaying weird in PhpStorm

Tags: terminal, console, phpstorm, powerline

Here is the problem :

[image]

### Config:

- PhpStorm 2019.1
- Cmder
- Windows 10
- Font: DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline
- Size: 14
- Line spacing: 1.0

I tried at least 5 fonts made for Powerline (Meslo, Droid, Roboto...)
I tried to change size and line spacing as well

Always the same ugly space.

With the exact same settings in VSCode, it renders correctly:

[image]

If someone has the solution...

PS:  Unfortunately, I can't tell if it's the same on older versions of PHPStorm, I'm just trying to switch from VSCode to PHPStorm these days

EDIT: I really think this a **line-height** problem, and that the issue comes from PHPStorm, since I don't have the problem in standalone Cmder. But the "line-height" option doesn't exist in PHPStorm (it is different from "line-spacing")

EDIT 2: I'm now pretty sure that it's related to phpstorm and has nothing to do with Cmder: The same thing happens with **powershell**:

[image: Powershell]

EDIT 3: It appears other people have encountered this issue and it seems that:

1. it isn't fixed yet
2. it isn't related to phpstorm but to many jet brains software integrated terminals

Some links on jetbrains bug tracker:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-41902
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192522#focus=streamItem-27-2883248.0-0

Comment: Is this a new issue? How does it look like on PhpSorm 2018.3.*?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't tell. I'm just trying to switch from VSCode to PHPStorm these days.

Comment: It's still an issue today (2020/03/010), but it should be fixed in 2020.1 version, according to Jetbrains team.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201379

Comment: seems resolved now at 2020.3 version